# Ajax Live Database check

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am making a registration table which will check if the cellphone number typed is in use like in twitter's username check. My code looks perfect but I keep getting 'Checking number availability' its like ajax is not POSTing my requests. Help Please :-)
here is the relevant ajax code bits

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()//When the dom is ready 
{
$("#cellphone_number").change(function() 
{ //if theres a change in the username textbox

var phonenumber = $("#cellphone_number").val();//Get the value in the username textbox
if(phonenumber.length == 13)//if the lenght equal to 13 characters
{
$("#availability_status").html('<align="absmiddle"><font color="#00FF33">Checking Number availability...</font>');
//Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"

$.ajax({  //Make the Ajax Request
    type: "POST", 
    url: "../Functions/ajax_check_number.php",  //file name
    data: ("number="+phonenumber),  //data
    success: function(server_response)
    {     
   $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 

    if(server_response == '0')//if ajax_check_username.php return value "0"
    { 
    $("#availability_status").html('<align="absmiddle"> <font color="#00FF33">Number is Available </font>  ');
    //add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
    }  
    else  if(server_response == '1')//if it returns "1"
    {  
     $("#availability_status").html('<align="absmiddle"> <font color="#FF0000">Number already in use</font>');
    }  

   });
   } 

  }); 

}
else
{

$("#availability_status").html('<font color="#FF0000">Number too short</font>');
//if in case the username is less than or equal 3 characters only 
}

return false;
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Please format the code properly

Comment: The code is all wonky... i'd fix it, but i dont have permissions...

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug to see if your request is being posted?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your effort. Managed to solve it. All you need to do is to add dataType = 'json' in the AJAX section where you define the url, data, type and success. My code was all wonky but someone cleaned it up(I'm new). Thanks. Now I don't know why it is not recognizing international phone number formats e.g +254..... must be the plus sign. Will solve it hopefully or someone help me. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now the code is edited at least to a level where even a beginner like me in AJAX and Javascript can understand. This does the job perfectly. Add some GIF images to give a "visual" response to the client side user especially when checking the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()//When the dom is ready
$(document).ready(function()//When the dom is ready
{
$("#cellphone_number").change(function()

{ //if there's a change in the cellphone_number textbox
var phonenumber = $("#cellphone_number").val();//Get the value in the username textbox
if(phonenumber.length == 13)//if the length is equal to 13 characters
{
$("#availability_status").html('< align="absmiddle" >&nbsp;<font 
color="#00FF33">Checking Number availability...</font>');
//Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"
$.ajax({  //Make the Ajax Request
type: "POST", 
url: "../Functions/ajax_check_number.php",  //file name
data: {number:$("#cellphone_number").val()},//data    
dataType: 'json',  
success: function(server_response)
{     
$("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request)
{     
if(server_response == '0')//if ajax_check_number.php return value "0"
{ 
$("#availability_status").html('<align="absmiddle"> <font color="#00FF33">Number is Available </font>  ');
//add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
}  
else  if(server_response == '1')//if it returns "1"
{  
 $("#availability_status").html('<align="absmiddle"> <font color="#FF0000">Number already in use</font>');
}
  });
 } 
 });
}
else
{

$("#availability_status").html('<font color="#FF0000">Number too short</font>');
//if in case the number is less than 13 characters only 
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $("#cellphone_number").change(function() 
    { 
        var phonenumber = $("#cellphone_number").val();
        if(phonenumber.length == 13)
        { 
            $("#availability_status").html('<align="absmiddle"><font color="#00FF33">Checking Number availability...</font>');  
            $.ajax(
            { 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "../Functions/ajax_check_number.php",
                data: {number: phonenumber},
                success: function(server_response) 
                { 
                    if(server_response == '0')
                    { 
                        $("#availability_status").html('<align="absmiddle"> <font color="#00FF33">Number is Available </font> '); 
                    } 
                    else if(server_response == '1')
                    { 
                        $("#availability_status").html('<align="absmiddle"> <font color="#FF0000">Number already in use</font>'); 
                    } 
                } 
            }); 
        } 
           else 
           { 

        $("#availability_status").html('<font color="#FF0000">Number too short</font>'); 
           } 
            }); 

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. It is helpful when you post code to also post an explanation of what it is doing, and why it might address the problem. Also, this question is a fairly old question and has been marked as complete. Your answer might get more attention on newer questions, which you can view on the homepage.